# android clickable textview selection sound effect occurs twice

Tags: android, textview

My android application has multiple pages and multiple clickable textviews.
i have coded them all the same way using xml onClick and clickable true
however on one particular page when i click on the textview FOR THE FIRST TIME two sound effects clicks can be heard in quick succession
this only happens the first time the page is displayed, to re create it i have to return to the previous page, then navigate to my "double click page" and it does it again.
does anybody have any idea why this is?

Comment: Can you post some code that we can look at?

Comment: not at the minute, however i dont think that will help. i have just used xml tags in my layout file to make the textview clickable and set the java method to call when clicked. the same method i have used in numerous layout files throughout my app, its just one instance that makes two selection sound effects when clicked on

Comment: Code always helps. :) What if you missed something? Reading your question I have to visualize what you might have done, which makes my answer just a guess. When you've got time, throw the code up if you can. It can only help.

Comment: will paste the code and xml layout when i have the chance to., thanks for looking at this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

School Boy error

my layout had the following widgets in a line

ImageButton, TextView, Image

they are all clickable and when any one of them are clicked they transfer the user to another related page.

what i had done was to performClick on the imageButton when the onClick java method specified in the textView was called.

i hang my head in shame :-(